# tel: link w/ extension working on iOS but not Android

Tags: android, iphone, html, tel

I have a link that looks something like:

```
<a href = "tel:1234567890pp2149">Call Support</a>
```

This link works perfectly fine when using an iOS device. When clicking the link while on Android however the phone attempts to dial `1234567890` (the number without the extension). What is the proper way to do this so that it will work across devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug/issue which may be due to the lack of standards around this feature, as comma,'W','P' are all specific implementations which could change as the Manufacturer may switch out the standard dialer for their own.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13684

Answer (score 0):

Try commas instead of 'p' for the pauses. I believe Android's pause character is a comma.

Comment: This yields the same result as using `p`

Comment: Is this link contained in a website, that is being viewed by an Android browser? If so, I would say URL encode the comma, so put '%2C' instead of ','

Comment: Yes. I tried using the encoded version but still getting the same result.

Comment: Are you trying this on an emulator or a phone? Apparently the emulator doesn't recognize pauses...per: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/AkEV1ugki9w

Comment: We're tried it on a couple of different physical devices with no success.

Comment: Other than trying a 'w,' I have no clue. Sorry :/ The Android browser may not be able to handle the pauses.