# as3 Flex AIR How to put a pause in a tel calURL?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, actionscript-3

I have some code that will aloow me to automatically type a phone number into the phone's native dialer pad when a button in the app is pressed:

```
// ---------------------- CALL SOMEONE!! ------------
 const callURL:String="tel:18002255288,1";
 var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
     navigateToURL(targetURL);
// ------------------------------------------------------
```

i know it is possible when dialing a number by hand to insert a comma, which symbolizes a "pause"

Really, it is for machines that are answering the phone. I would like it to dial the number, immediately pause, and then immediately dial the extension of the place the call should go.

Answer (score 1):

According to [tel: link w/ extension working on iOS but not Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646614/tel-link-w-extension-working-on-ios-but-not-android), you can use `p` as a pause character for iOS, and `,` for Android.