# html href="tel:4442727,2" or href="tel:4442727p2" does not work on Android

Tags: android, html

As title mentions, in my mobile web site I can call a number but I need to add a 2-3 seconds pause to the call in order to dial the extension. No matter what I tried I cannot achieve this. Both href="tel:4442727,2" nor href="tel:4442727p2" works on android (I tested on 5.1). When I use a comma it works on iOS but not on Android What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to three commas - I've seen this correct the problem in the past.

```
href="tel:4442727,,,2"
```

Alternatively, replace the comma with a 'w' and Android will dial the phone number then prompt you to hit a button before dialling the extension.

Comment: I tried both href=''tel:4442727,,,2" and href="tel:4442727w2" but they are not working. Extension numbers are copied into the number input but does not dial or wait.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this has been an issue for a number of years - could be a bug.  The way you're doing it is definitely the recommended way.

Comment: My answer from years ago may still be valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646614/tel-link-w-extension-working-on-ios-but-not-android/12647635#12647635

Comment: Unfortunately no, it seems like it is a reported bug since 2011. I've started to inspect android's dialer code.